# How to add a footnote separator rule

Tags: footnotes, rules, ieeetran

I'm using `\documentclass{IEEEtran}`. I've tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [`IEEEtran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) class file [`IEEEtran.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls),

> IEEE uses a footnote rule only for `\thanks` [using] a "one-shot" system [...]

Additionally, this is only active with the `compsoc` document class option. Under that option, `\footnoterule`  - the macro responsible for inserting the footnote rule (only when using `\thanks`, remember) resembles:

```
\makeatletter
\def\footnoterule{\relax%
  \kern-5pt
  \hbox to \columnwidth{\hfill\vrule width 0.5\columnwidth height 0.4pt\hfill}
  \kern4.6pt}
\makeatother
```

The above `\footnoterule` matches the original class-version exactly, except for the conditionals that prevent setting it outside of `compsoc`, as well as the `\thanks`-only restriction. Additionally, it's obvious that it centres the horizontal line. Here's a minimal example showing the output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\footnoterule{\relax%
  \kern-5pt
  \hbox to \columnwidth{\hfill\vrule width 0.5\columnwidth height 0.4pt\hfill}
  \kern4.6pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text\footnote{\lipsum[2]}.

\end{document}
```